# Custom Implementing multileg option orders in QuickFIX 4.2

Tags: c++, windows, quickfix

Multileg option orders are not supported in FIX Protocol 4.2. I've implemented custom tags but never a new message type. Can anyone provide a roadmap of the steps to implement NewOrderMultileg msgtype="AB" into the QuickFix FIX42 namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This should help or more or less this is how you do it.](http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/custom-fields-groups-and-messages.html) It is for QuickFIX/N, but the method of adding new messages is consistent for all Quickfix libraries.

Or another way is hijack it from the data dictionary for the FIX version where it exists. I believe all versions of the data dictionary are in the quickfix releases. But you need to be careful how you do it i.e. check for fields, repeating group etc.

But you might have to add some code if the new message class doesn't exist at all and you will have to engineer it to fit in your existing library. This might need some work and may throw up some unlikely errors.  For this you can easily refer to a quickfix library version which does have the class.

Comment: The hijack method seems to make the most sense to me. Once everything is in place do you need to rebuild the QuickFIX libraries, etc? Otherwise how would the appropriate overloaded onMessage(....) userexit method be invoked?

Comment: Don't C++ header files need to be added/updated as well?

Comment: Aha I forgot to mention about the class, because I was assuming you were only modifying an existing class. Will add that to the answer.

Comment: ok. The NewOrderMultileg class is defined in FIX 4.3. Is all I need to do is create the same class in the FIX 4.2 namespace, add any supporting new field and tag values then rebuild my application? Or do I also have to rebuild the entire quickfix version itself once I added and updated the appropriate *.h  header include files?

Comment: I found this link very helpful. https://xiongzou.wordpress.com/2012/11/10/quickfix-custom-messagesclasses-tutorial-by-brian-erst/ At some point it tells you to run "generate" from the command line in \quickfix\spec directory. Be warned that there's a bug in the GeneratorCPP.rb script that causes faulty output for repeating Groups.